# it is good for you

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

a. It hurts me remembering those days.

b. It bothers me talking to him.

c. It is good for you eating fruit and vegetables.

d. It is nice sitting here.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

I think they are all fine, however I'd use the infinitive in the first three cases. I don't know why (d) sounds natural to me and the other three not so much.

Answer (score 2):

For me (Australian English native), a and d are perfectly idiomatic. b is ok, but sounds more natural around the other way ("Talking to him bothers me").

Whereas **c** sounds pretty dubious, and is much better around the other way: "Eating fruit and vegetables is good for you", or with the infinitive: "It is good for you to eat fruit and vegetables".

I can't really think of a clear reason why that is the case, though.